# Ruby 2.2.4 on Openshift Online without Docker

Tags: ruby, openshift, ruby-2.2

I'm using Openshift Online (bronze) to host a rails app and I'd like to upgrade from the standard Ruby 2.0 cartridge to Ruby 2.2.4 so that I can run Rails 5.

I tried following this tutorial [Using Openshift S2I docker images to build ruby application containers](http://nts.strzibny.name/using-openshift-s2i-docker-images-to-build-ruby-application-containers/) but it leaves me with a gazillion other things to do (I'm a Docker noob), and plus it's quite a jump to go from using a ready-made Openshift cartidge that takes 10 seconds to provision, to building my own Docker container and doing a ton of other stuff I know nothing about.

Does anyone know of a simple way to get Ruby 2.2 onto my Openshift Online gear or is Docker the only way to go?

Failing that, do any Openshift Online contributers who use this site know if Ruby 2.2.4 will be made available as a default cartridge anytime soon so that we don't have to take such an enormous technical leap to get a Rails 5 app running on Openshift Online?

Comment: The current version of OpenShift Online is not supporting the S2I you have referred to. That would be [OpenShift Origin](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases), which is not available as OpenShift Online presently. You can post your idea of a Ruby 2.2 cartridge for OpenShift Online [here](https://openshift.uservoice.com/) and get others to vote for it.

Comment: Thanks @JiriFiala I'll close the question now.